# Can a component receive an array of components for an unknown number of slots?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm building a generic datatable that, in addition to the datatable, has a header area with a title and record count. I'd also like to have the option to put other components in this header without knowing what they will be. For example, some uses of this datatable will have one or two progress bars in the headers. Others might have a button group or an button icon.

I'd like to give the callers of this datatable the ability to send an array of components to the datatable, and then it'll so something like this:

```html
<div if:true={headerComponents.length}>
    <slot name="headerComponents">
        <div for:each={headerComponents} for:item={component}>
            {component}
        </div>
    </slot>
</div>
```

But how can I get the caller to pass an array of configured components, this button bar with these buttons, this progress bar with this level? How can I create them programmatically so they can be passed as an array?

Answer (score 0):

Slots automatically accept an "array" of content, so there's no need to do anything extra. Consider this trivial example:

## app.html

```
<template>
    <c-child>
        <div slot="extra">This is extra stuff.</div>
        <div slot="extra">And so is this!</div>
    </c-child>
    <c-child></c-child>
</template>
```

## child.html

```
<template>
    <slot name="extra">And default content goes here</slot>
</template>
```

If nothing is in the slot, then the default (if any) will be rendered.

[Demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/MZupLWwnSyoVaIqKvSSo/).

Note that LWC doesn't have support for creating elements via `document.createElement` or anything like that, so everything has to be in markup (the template code), but you can write whatever code you want to include any number of components in a slot.

Note that I use the `div` tag, but this could easily be any standard HTML or custom component that you write.